# Parsing Very Hierarchical XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML which I need to parse which is going to be very hierarchical and quite a few options at each level of the hierarchy.

A sample of the XML is below:

```
<Maplet MapletName="house" SizeX="15" SizeY="11" Tiled="true" TileID="4" Walled="true" WindowProbability="20">
  <MapletContents>
    <MapletContentsItem Position="Sides" ItemID="37" ItemCategory="mundaneitems" MaxAmount="2" ProbabilityPercentage="75" />
    <MapletContentsMaplet Position="Middle" MaxAmount="2" ProbabilityPercentage="100">
      <Maplet MapletName="Chairs" SizeX="3" SizeY="3" Tiled="false" Walled="false">
        <MapletContents>
          <MapletContentsItemTag Position="Fixed" x="1" y="1" Category="mundaneitems" MaxAmount="1" ProbabilityPercentage="100" Tag="table"/>
        </MapletContents>
      </Maplet>
    </MapletContentsMaplet>
  </MapletContents>
</Maplet>
```

As you can see from the structure, "MapletContentsMaplet" contain "Maplets", so the XML could very easily be much bigger with sub-maplets inside it.

In the end, I will want to create a number of C# objects which have this exact hierarchy.

I've looked at a TON of XML-parsing questions, and aside from still being confused between the various classes for parsing XML - the solution I 'have' sounds horribly clunky for a 'language' which is supposed to be designed to be hiearchical.

The solution I have is as follows:

1. Start at the node
2. Parse the Attributes
3. Go to the Nth child and parse the attributes/create the objects as required
4. If the Nth child has its own children, recurr to 1 with the child as the focus.

This sounds like a ton and a half of work. Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT - I don't know how "deep" the hierarchy will go, and the children can be any of a number of possible 'types' , so I can't really use 'search' using the DOM notation or whatever.

Comment: That solution seems fine to me.

Comment: If you are going to use objects then route you want to go down is serialisation. If you get that right, the xml will be transparent

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "language design to be hierarchical" ;0

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - The XML is going to be hand-written, I can't just serialise stuff I already have. I need to somehow deserialise it.

Comment: yeah the more hierarchical the better, especially for serialisation or xmlreader/writer

Comment: oh.., wasn't clear that

Comment: Do you have a scheme for your document?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your objects will have the same hierarchy as the xml I would simply use the XMLSerializer class with a generic type for this.

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
   var serializer = new XmlSerializer(Typeof(T));
   using(var textReader = new XMLTextReader(newStringReader(xml)))
   {
     return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
   }
}
```